# Top N reason for the month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to display Top N reason for the month based to below data model in power BI.

Tables:
Date ([fulldate,date],[ReportMonth varchar(50) format mmmyy])
,Reason ([ReasonDate,date],[Reason varchar(500)]

The top filter should display top 3 reasons for the month using DAX.It should not display the top 3 reasons on overall count.The filter will be on ReportMonth column to find the top 3 reasons

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Intersect with values on the DAX measure for both of the above tables and it worked for me.

ReasonCount=Calculate(Count(Reason),Intersect(Values(Reason),Values(Date)))

Be careful with the table sequence in intersect they incur different results for different combination.Intersect(T1,T2) is not equal to Intersect(T2,T1).

Thanks.